VBA .cells recognizes value in some cells but not others
I'm trying to iterate through a list of values in excel to populate certain parts of a word document. The VBA script finds the strings listed in the arrays declared at the top ("revArrayY1", etc) and replaces that text with corresponding values in a spreadsheet using the .Cells function to grab the value. It worked at first, but when adding another row to the list of values in excel to populate, the .Cells function won't recognize the value in the new cell. All I did was shift the cells in excel up to make room for the new row and add a new string to the array.
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim wApp As Object ' Change to "Object" for late binding
    Dim wdoc As Object ' Change to "Object" for late binding
    Dim custN As String, path As String
    Dim revArrayY1 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    Dim revArrayY2 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    Dim revArrayY3 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    Dim revArrayY4 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    Dim revArrayY5 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    
    Dim COGArrayY1 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    Dim COGArrayY2 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    Dim COGArrayY3 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    Dim COGArrayY4 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    Dim COGArrayY5 As Variant ' Declare as Variant for now
    
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlWS As Object
    
    ' Initialize Excel objects
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:[file path]/ Financials.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets("Cashflow") ' Change "Cashflow" to your sheet name
    
    ' Sales Arrays
    revArrayY1 = Array("<BeerSalesY1>", "<WineSalesY1>", "<SpiritSalesY1>", "<KDSalesY1>", "<BoochSalesY1>", "<VenueSalesY1>", "<KCSalesY1>", "<MealSalesY1>", "<RevFcstY1>")
    revArrayY2 = Array("<BeerSalesY2>", "<WineSalesY2>", "<SpiritSalesY2>", "<KDSalesY2>", "<BoochSalesY2>", "<VenueSalesY2>", "<KCSalesY2>", "<MealSalesY2>", "<RevFcstY2>")
    revArrayY3 = Array("<BeerSalesY3>", "<WineSalesY3>", "<SpiritSalesY3>", "<KDSalesY3>", "<BoochSalesY3>", "<VenueSalesY3>", "<KCSalesY3>", "<MealSalesY3>")
    revArrayY4 = Array("<BeerSalesY4>", "<WineSalesY4>", "<SpiritSalesY4>", "<KDSalesY4>", "<BoochSalesY4>", "<VenueSalesY4>", "<KCSalesY4>", "<MealSalesY4>")
    revArrayY5 = Array("<BeerSalesY5>", "<WineSalesY5>", "<SpiritSalesY5>", "<KDSalesY5>", "<BoochSalesY5>", "<VenueSalesY5>", "<KCSalesY5>", "<MealSalesY5>")
    
    'COGS Arrays
    COGArrayY1 = Array("<COGBeerY1>", "<COGWineY1>", "<COGSpiritY1>", "<COGKDY1>", "<COGBoochY1>", "<COGVenueY1>", "<COGKCY1>", "<COGMealY1>")
    COGArrayY2 = Array("<COGBeerY2>", "<COGWineY2>", "<COGSpiritY2>", "<COGKDY2>", "<COGBoochY2>", "<COGVenueY2>", "<COGKCY2>", "<COGMealY2>")
    COGArrayY3 = Array("<COGBeerY3>", "<COGWineY3>", "<COGSpiritY3>", "<COGKDY3>", "<COGBoochY3>", "<COGVenueY3>", "<COGKCY3>", "<COGMealY3>")
    COGArrayY4 = Array("<COGBeerY4>", "<COGWineY4>", "<COGSpiritY4>", "<COGKDY4>", "<COGBoochY4>", "<COGVenueY4>", "<COGKCY4>", "<COGMealY4>")
    COGArrayY5 = Array("<COGBeerY5>", "<COGWineY5>", "<COGSpiritY5>", "<COGKDY5>", "<COGBoochY5>", "<COGVenueY5>", "<COGKCY5>", "<COGMealY5>")
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Long
    r = 1
    
    ' Loop through rows of Excel worksheet
    Do While r < 2
        ' Create new instance of Word application
        Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wApp.Visible = True
        
        ' Open the Word document
        Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:[file path]/Business Plan.dotx")
        
    ' Loop through Revenue Projections
        ' Loop through the array of strings
        i = 0
        For i = LBound(revArrayY1) To UBound(revArrayY1)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = revArrayY1(i)
                 Debug.Print xlWS.Cells(7 + i, 4).Value
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(7 + i, 10).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i
        
        i = 0
        For i = LBound(revArrayY2) To UBound(revArrayY2)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = revArrayY2(i)
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(22 + i, 10).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i
        
       i = 0
        For i = LBound(revArrayY3) To UBound(revArrayY3)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = revArrayY3(i)
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(37 + i, 10).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i
        
        i = 0
        For i = LBound(revArrayY4) To UBound(revArrayY4)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = revArrayY4(i)
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(53 + i, 10).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i
        
        i = 0
        For i = LBound(revArrayY5) To UBound(revArrayY5)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = revArrayY5(i)
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(69 + i, 10).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i
        
' Loop through COGS projections
        i = 0
        For i = LBound(COGArrayY1) To UBound(COGArrayY1)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = COGArrayY1(i)
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(7 + i, 13).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i
        
        i = 0
        For i = LBound(COGArrayY2) To UBound(COGArrayY2)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = COGArrayY2(i)
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(22 + i, 13).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i
        
        i = 0
        For i = LBound(COGArrayY3) To UBound(COGArrayY3)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = COGArrayY3(i)
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(38 + i, 13).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i
        
        i = 0
        For i = LBound(COGArrayY4) To UBound(COGArrayY4)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = COGArrayY4(i)
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(54 + i, 13).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i

        i = 0
        For i = LBound(COGArrayY5) To UBound(COGArrayY5)
            ' Find and replace text in Word document
            With wdoc.Content.Find
                .Text = COGArrayY5(i)
                .Replacement.Text = CStr(Round(xlWS.Cells(70 + i, 13).Value / 1000, 0))
                .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
            End With
        Next i
        
        ' Save the Word document
        custN = xlWS.Cells(r, 1).Value
        path = "C:[file path]\"
        wdoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=path, FileFormat:=16, AddToRecentFiles:=False ' FileFormat 16 is wdFormatXMLDocument
        
        ' Close Word document
        wdoc.Close
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    
    ' Close Excel workbook and application
    xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    xlApp.Quit
    
    ' Release objects from memory
    Set xlWS = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set wdoc = Nothing
    Set wApp = Nothing
End Sub




I can print the index "i" and see that the FOR loop is iterating over the whole array and I have triple checked to make sure I am using the correct row and column numbers. I also put an arbitrary number into an arbitrary cell and just tried to print that cell and .Cells won't recognize that value either and it won't Debug.Print the value either. It seems like there came a point where it would only recognize the values in cells that I previously had. I thought maybe it was something wrong with the formatting of the cell, so I copied and pasted the value from a cell that is working and it still doesn't recognize the value. Furthermore, even though this doesn't throw an error in the first two for loops (it just doesn't work for the last couple values) when it gets to the FOR loop iterating over "revArrayY3" it throws a "Type Mismatch Error" even though all values are formatted the same and the FOR loops are identical.

Do While r < 2 - your loop only executes once?

Yes that was just a remanent of a pervious version that I kept just in case and doesn't do anything for now.

Are you running this in Excel?

Yes in a Macro enabled worksheet.

Final code after getting a copy of your Excel file.
Word-related parts are commented out, since I don't have the template document.
Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim wApp As Object, wdoc As Object
    Dim custN As String, path As String
    Dim revArray As Variant, revArrayRows  As Variant
    Dim COGArray As Variant, COGArrayRows
    Dim xlWB As Object, xlWS As Object
    Dim i As Long, yr As Long, rw As Long, lbl As String, c As Range, v As String
    
    'label Arrays
    revArray = Array("BeerSales", "WineSales", "SpiritSales", "KDSales", _
                     "BoochSales", "VenueSales", "KCSales", "MealSales", "RevFcst")
    
    COGArray = Array("COGBeer", "COGWine", "COGSpirit", "COGKD", "COGBooch", _
                    "COGVenue", "COGKC", "COGMeal", "COGFcst")
    
    'Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\sheph\Documents\Project Files\Fats Industries\Botanical Brews\Business Plan and Financials/Botanical Brews Financials.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cashflow") ' Change "Cashflow" to your sheet name
    
    'Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") ' Create new instance of Word application
    'wApp.Visible = True
    'Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\sheph\Documents\Project Files\Fats Industries\Botanical Brews\Business Plan and Financials/Botanical Brews Business Plan.dotx") ' Open the Word document
    
    For yr = 1 To 5  'loop years 1-5
        
        m = Application.Match("Year " & yr, xlWS.Columns("A"), 0) 'find the year on the data sheet
        If Not IsError(m) Then  'got a match?
            rw = m + 3 'data starts 3 rows down from year
            Debug.Print "-------Year " & yr & ": Row# " & rw & " ------------"
        Else
            MsgBox "No 'Year " & yr & "' in ColA on data sheet", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        For i = LBound(revArray) To UBound(revArray)
            lbl = "<" & revArray(i) & "Y" & yr & ">"
            Set c = xlWS.Cells(rw + i, "J")
            v = CStr(Round(c.Value / 1000, 0))
            'if you get a "type mismatch" error on the next line it's likely because `c` value is not numeric
            Debug.Print "Got value '" & v & "' from " & c.Address(False, False) & " for " & lbl
            'ReplaceAll wdoc, lbl, v
        Next i
        
        For i = LBound(COGArray) To UBound(COGArray)
            lbl = "<" & COGArray(i) & "Y" & yr & ">"
            Set c = xlWS.Cells(rw + i, "M")
            v = CStr(Round(c.Value / 1000, 0))
            Debug.Print "Got value '" & v & "' from " & c.Address(False, False) & " for " & lbl
            'ReplaceAll wdoc, lbl, v
        Next i
    Next yr
    'xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        
'    custN = xlWS.Cells(1, 1).Value ' Save the Word document
'    path = "C:C:\Users\sheph\Documents\Project Files\Fats Industries\Botanical Brews\Business Plan and Financials\"
'    wdoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=path, FileFormat:=16, AddToRecentFiles:=False ' 16 is wdFormatXMLDocument
'    wdoc.Close
'    wApp.Quit
End Sub

'In Word document `doc`, replace all instances of `findWhat` with `replaceWith`
Sub ReplaceAll(doc As Object, findWhat As String, replaceWith As String)
    'Debug.Print "Replacing '" & findWhat & "' with '" & replaceWith & "'"
    With doc.Content.Find
        .Text = findWhat
        .Replacement.Text = replaceWith
        .Execute Replace:=2 ' wdReplaceAll constant value is 2
    End With
End Sub


Thanks Tim Williams! You whipped that up quick. Being new to VBA that will take some time to digest. I did run it though and I'm having the same issues so I'm guessing its not the code but something within the spreadsheet

Edited to add some Debug output which might be useful in figuring out the problem...  If you're getting Type mismatch error then maybe some of your Excel cell values aren't numeric.

It will iterate and replace the values from J7-J13, but from J14 on it just won't recognize the value. The values are definitely numeric and the cells are formatted as currency, just like the ones that work. J14 and J15 are '0' in the word doc and from then on it doesn't replace at all.

For (eg) "rev" you have blocks of 9, so years 1-5 that's J7:J15, J22:J30, J37:J45, J53:J61 and J69:J77. If that's not what you want/expect then you need to explain how it should be different.  I can take a look if you're willing to share the XL file via email.

I've copied the address. Will forward momentarily

Fixed one line above (see ##FIX).  Otherwise - the copy you sent seems to be reading fine.  Did you check the output in the Immediate pane?

Is the macro in a separate file, or is it contained in the Excel file where the data is?  If it's in the same file you can skip the Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open(..) and refer to ThisWorkbook instead.

So Set xlWS = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Cashflow")
